# Parse iOS: Array of Pointer check if object empty

Tags: ios, arrays, pointers, reference

We've got an array of pointers in Table A referencing to user object ids. Some of these references are invalid, because the objects the pointers refer to have been deleted. Others are still valid. So the call PFObject.fetchAllIfNeeded throws an "object does not exist" - error for sure - and I am not able to receive the existing objects. But how can I check before the fetchAllIfNeeded call which object still exists in an efficient way and only conduct the fetchAllIfNeeded call on these?

Comment: if PFObject != nil { PFObject.fetchAllIfNeeded }

Comment: PFObject is not a real object and thus never nil, it's a Parse class offering the "fetchAllIfNeeded" method for fetching multiple objects at once